# Quartz delayed starting

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am running into an issue where quartz-service.xml (using quartz 1.8.6 with JBOSS 5.1.x) is deploying before the application that contains the class files to be run. Is there a way to delay the start of quartz?

My quartz-service.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
    <mbean code="org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService" name="user:service=QuartzService,name=QuartzService">
    <attribute name="JndiName">Quartz Scheduler</attribute>
    <attribute name="Properties">
        org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
        org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
        org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
        org.quartz.scheduler.xaTransacted = false
        org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
        org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
        org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 4
        org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
        org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class =  org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
        org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = D:/JBoss-5.1.0/quartz-config.xml
        org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
        org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 120
        org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
    </attribute>
    </mbean>
</server>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Spring, there is a property named `startupDelay`, for example:

```
<property name="startupDelay" value="10"/>
```

In java, you can call the method `startDelayed()` on the Scheduler instance, for example:

```
scheduler.startDelayed(10);
```

So you should find it out in JBOSS what the property is. Hope it helps.

Comment: Start delay value should be given in seconds, your config means 10 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

Below parameter can be used in Spring with Quartz Schedular maven dependency where you can specify start delay in milliseconds

```
<property name="startDelay" value="60000" />
```

Comment: Start delay value should be given in SECONDS, not milliseconds. That is, value="60" for one minute delay.